# mouse position and give the position color

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mouseevent, pixel

How can I get the color of a pixel at the location of the cursor? I know how to get the mouses position using MousePosition but I can not figure out how to get the pixel color at that location. I write the code put I have no result when run

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


                    s= pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);        

                    bitmap.SetPixel(s.X / 40, s.Y / 40, Color.Red);

                    }
```

Comment: Well, of course not, you didn't write the code.  Use the MouseMove event and bitmap.GetPixel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use the `e.Location` point in the parameter of the `Mouseclick` event:

```
Color c = ( (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
```

This assumes that indeed the bitmap is in the `PicturBox`'s `Image`, not painted on top of the `Control`..

Make sure the event is actually hooked up!

To set a clicked pixel to, say red, you would get the `Bitmap` from the PB's `Image` and set the pixels, then move the `Bitmap` back in::

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
bmp.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Red);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

also in the `MouseClick` event.

If you want to get a larger mark you should use the `Graphics` methods, maybe like this:

```
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
   G.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, e.X - 3, e.Y - 3, 6, 6);
}
```

**Update:** To combine getting and setting you could write:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
Color target = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255); 
Color c == bmp .GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
if (c == target ) 
    {
       bmp.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Red);
       pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
else MessageBox.Show("Click only on white spots! You have hit " + c.ToString(),
                     "Wrong spot! ");
```

Comment: sorry but when use this                                                                          Color c = ( (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);                              where I put the color for ex: red or any color I use the SetPixel to give pixel the color

Comment: Well you can use SetPixel just the same here: `( (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, color.Red);` - But are you sure you know (or have told us)  what you want to achieve? Why read the color if you then set it to red?

Comment: I do this but when run and click  nothing happen

Comment: The clicked pixel should turn red. But a single pixel is rather small; What is the SizeMode of the pictureBox?

Comment: SizeMode Normal .I change it to zoom but the same problem what is the solve please

Comment: ,sorry I can't  move this discussion to chat because my reputation not enough,I have another question please ,as you know image have clear position "white"and other have color "drawing" I want if I click on the drawing give me message for example "not click here" how can do this please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want something like: if (c != Color.White) MessageBox.Show("message", "title");`?

Comment: Yes like this when I clicking first one it should be check if the position is clear because I can't select position for example on obstacle (or any thing is drawing just on clear space click to select the  point )

Comment: I apologize for inconvenience, I want if(position ==Color.White) make the position(e.X, e.Y) red how can do this with bmp.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Red)

Comment: Whoops, sorry, two errors in the code. The obvious one was the single `=` in the if clause. The much less obvious one was comapring a real color from the `GetPixel` with a `KnownColor`. Although they are identical they are not equal and the comparison fails.  See the updated (and tested) code!